# PostgreSQL 9.5: Return columns based on input parameter

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have the following table.

**Table**:

```
CREATE TABLE tblTest
(
    Column1 int,
    Column2 int,
    Column3 int,
    Column11 int,
    Column111 int,
    Column1111 int,
    Column22 int,
    Column222 int,
    Column33 int
);
```

**Records**:

```
INSERT INTO tblTest VALUES(1,2,3,11,111,1111,22,222,33);
```

I am writting `FUNCTION` to return the result from above table based on passed parameter.

The parameter `p_ColumnName` is used to pass the column name. Based on column name the list of columns needs to be display.

**Function**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ufn_test
(
    p_ColumnName text
)
RETURNS -- ? How to specify the dynamic return type or dynamic column list ?
AS

$BODY$

DECLARE v_ColumnsList text;
    v_query text;
BEGIN

    IF p_ColumnName = 'Column1'
    THEN
        v_ColumnsList := 'Column11,Column111,Column1111';

    ELSIF p_ColumnName = 'Column2'
    THEN
        v_ColumnsList := 'Column22,Column222';

    ELSIF p_ColumnName = 'Column3'
    THEN
        v_ColumnsList := 'Column33';

    END IF;

    v_query := 'SELECT '|| v_ColumnsList ||' FROM tblTest';

    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE v_query;

END;

$BODY$

LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Comment: is there a reason for such a structure? assuming columns are independent from each other typically it is converted into set of multiple rows "primary key + property id + value"

Comment: probably the return type you want is `int[]`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you are using a type [RefCursor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-cursors.html) in Returns.

Base on the language you are using (SQL, Java ...), you can get data from this Cursor.

So, your function will become to

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ufn_test( p_ColumnName text )
RETURNS refcursor AS
$BODY$
DECLARE 
    v_ColumnsList text;
    v_query text;
    ref_cursor refcursor;
BEGIN

    IF (p_ColumnName = 'Column1') THEN
        v_ColumnsList := 'Column11,Column111,Column1111';
    ELSIF (p_ColumnName = 'Column2') THEN
        v_ColumnsList := 'Column22,Column222';
    ELSIF (p_ColumnName = 'Column3') THEN
        v_ColumnsList := 'Column33';
    END IF;

    v_query := 'SELECT '|| v_ColumnsList ||' FROM tblTest';

    OPEN ref_cursor FOR EXECUTE (v_query);

    RETURN ref_cursor;

END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Hopefully it will help you.